# How to save and restore NSScrollView scroll position in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, scroll, nstableview

In a macOS project I'm trying to get and set the scroll cursor position of a NSTableView the code seems to work because don't appairs errors but the cursor don't update.

```
   var clipOrigin = tableView.enclosingScrollView?.contentView.bounds.origin // get the position
   clipOrigin = CGPoint (x: 0.0, y: 3.0) // set a new position
   tableView.enclosingScrollView?.contentView.scroll(to: clipOrigin!) // set the new position
```

Am I forgetting something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep same NSTableView scrolled position while inserting rows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41965201/2227743)

Comment: Note also: `tableView.enclosingScrollView?.contentView` is the same as just `tableView`.

Answer (score -1):

`contentView.bounds.origin` will almost certainly give you a point at `0,0` pretty much always as that's not the value you are expecting. `bounds` tell you an information about a position of the view which displays the canvas, not the inner offset of the scrolled document.

I guess one `-documentRect` or `-documentVisibleRect` properties contains the proper offset value you're looking for.